# x_test or x_test_transformed on prediction = gs.best_estimator_.predict(X_?)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using scikit-learn libraries and I've a doubt if I need to use X_test or X_test_transformed on gs.best_estimator_.predict(x_?).

Suppose that I already fit my gs (gridsearch object) ( gs = gs.fit(X_train,Y_train)) instance by defining a pipeline with one transformer like standardScaler() and one MLPclassifier.
In sereval example what I see is:

```
clf = gs.best_estimator_
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predicted = clf.predict(X_test)
```

It's clear that X_test will go through my defined pipeline, because the best estimator come from there, but how can I sure that on X_test will be apply the transform method before being classified in the last step? Thus, my doubt is:
Do I need to first transform X_test before applying for `gs.best_estimator_.predict(???)`?
Thanks

Just to answer @bakka :
below my code :

  `pipeline =make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(24,),activation="logistic",solver='lbgfs',alpha=1e-01,random_state=42,tol=1e-4,max_iter=10000))
hidden_layer_size_range = [24,25,26]
activation_range = ['identity','logistic','tanh','relu']
solver_range = ['lbfgs','sgd','adam']
alpha_range = [1e-1,1e-2,1e-3,1e-4,1e-5,1e-6,1e-7]
learning_rate_range = ['constant','adaptive']
param_grid = {'mlpclassifier__hidden_layer_sizes': hidden_layer_size_range, 'mlpclassifier__activation': activation_range,'mlpclassifier__solver': solver_range,'mlpclassifier__alpha': alpha_range,'mlpclassifier__learning_rate': learning_rate_range}
gs = GridSearchCV(pipeline,param_grid,scoring='accuracy',n_jobs=-1,cv=5)
gs = gs.fit(X_train,Y_train)`

Comment: How did you define GridSearchCV? I guess you only fed it with MLP Classifier, means that you were only searching best parameter for MLP Classifier. Am I right? Then you have to transform your test data as you did to train data

Comment: gs = GridSearchCV(your_estimator, params, ...). What is your_estimator?

Comment: please read above

Comment: Then you don't need to transform `X_test`

Comment: Ok,thanks.Thus,once my GridSearchCV object has a transformer in place,defined via pipeline,  any test data that I feed it will automatically be transformed (By applying the transform method) in background before applying predict method ? –

Comment: I'm sure :). It's like when you fit a pipeline. However be careful at data preprocessing. I suggest you to transform train+test data together, the split it after that.

Comment: @bakka Wrong. Never transform first and split after. Always split first and then do the learning of transformation from train and apply that on test.

Comment: Another question if I may: the value I got from the score method of the following pipeline ojbect  `clf = gs.best_estimator clf.fit(X_train,Y_train) clf.score(X_test,Y_test)` is equal to the score value got by the score method of MLPclassifier object `clf_best = clf._final_estimator clf_best.fit(X_train_transformed,Y_train) clf_best.score(X_test_transformed,Y_test)`  ???

Comment: OK, I just checked it out by running that above code and I get same values. Thus, yes they are equivalent